# How to bring solar panel wires inside house?

Tags: electrical, walls, electrical-panel, wire, solar-panels

I have a pretty simple solar panel setup in the backyard which links to the charge controller to the batteries.

I wanted to run wires inside the house so I can use it for smaller stuff like charging phones and laptops since I have to go in the backyard everytime.

I saw a tutorial on drilling through the wall for cable wires but this is electrical so I'm hesitating. How do most people get their power inside the house? Want to stay off grid since the power is not much.

Comment: Any idea how many amps this cable is going to be carrying?

Comment: You can either go underground through conduit, or overhead into a weatherhead/mast style entry.

Comment: @JPhi1618, I'm guessing 15 amps since they're discussing light loading (charging cell phones, laptops).

Comment: @elrobis it might be in the 1800VA class, but with solar it is often low voltage DC.  Upside, liberal NEC rules since it's not a lethal voltage.  Downside, big amps and big voltage drop.  i've seen solar setups where 1" aluminum busbar would not be excessive.

Comment: This is a simple 200-watt panel setup so not many amps. I'd rather find a way to send a wire through the wall. I can see the panels from my bedroom - it's less than 1 feet. I can send the wire through the window but if I need to close the window - it's a problem. I can't drill a dole since it'll crack the window.